# <base> works selectively/weirdly -- is it normal?

Tags: php, html, radix

I use the following throughout the project and until now did not notice an issue:

```
   include '../titleBar.php';
   require_once '../navBar.php';
   require_once '../theDatabase.php'; // functions for the UI and DB access
   require_once '../globals.php'; // variables and statics used throughout
```

The above has worked FINE for 3 weeks.  The reason for the ../ before the filenames is: the statements above appears in user subfolders in user-specific files such as **FOO_x.php** that are specific to user-entered data -- only the above include and require_once files involve common code, and the common code is one directory above the subfolders in the root web site directory.

So I added this new bit of code and it does not pull in the style sheet:

```
   include '../titleBar.php';
   require_once '../navBar.php';
   require_once '../theDatabase.php';
   require_once '../globals.php';

   <html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../globalStyles.css" />
```

I changed it to this and the stylesheet get pulled in fine to the user-specific file FOO_x.php:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="globalStyles.css" />
```

KEEP IN MIND -- the above link rel is in the file **FOO_x.php** that is in a subdirectory of the root web site.
AND -- the file 'globalStyles.css' is.....NOT IN the subdirectory where FOO_x.php resides.

The file 'globalStyles.css' is one level ABOVE the folder containing FOO_x.php.

So why/how could href = globalStyles.css  even work?  Well IT DOES.

Because for the past 3 weeks, the 2nd file 'navBar.php' in the include/require list at the top of FOO_x.php 
has the following statement in it:

```
     <base href='http://localhost/theSiteRootFolder/'></base>
```

So when I tried

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../globalStyles.css" />
```

and none of its styles appeared on the FOO_x.php page, I switched it to

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="globalStyles.css" />
```

and suddenly the styles appeared.  THEN I remembered 'long ago' I'd put the 'base' statement
in navBar.php.

Next I figured "Okay, if the link rel statement is using the 'base' statement from navBar.php -- 
then the require_once for the files **theDatabase.php** and **globals.php** DO NOT NEED the ../ either.
After all, these 2 files occur *after* the 'base' statement in require_once navBar.php, just as the
link rel statement does."  Logical (to me).

So I changed the top of the file FOO_x.php to this:

```
   include '../titleBar.php';
   require_once '../navBar.php';
   // these next 2 file 'requires'  should work -- the navBar.php declared a 'base' to be the folder above this one
   require_once 'theDatabase.php';
   require_once 'globals.php';
```

I figured  "once navBar.php is pulled in with its base statement, since apparently the link rel insists that
globalStyles.css cannot have the ../ -- then neither should theDatabase.php or globals.php.

Because all 3 of these statements appear AFTER the 'base' statement's **href='http://localhost/theSiteRootFolder**
relative path root.

Yet only the link rel 'honors' or pays attetion to the 'base' statement declared above it in navBar.php.

Why?  I don't get why, since navBar.php establishes the 'base' to which all relative paths resolve --
why then does this NOT work:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../globalStyles.css" />
```

but these work FINE?

```
   include '../titleBar.php';
   require_once '../navBar.php';
   // okay the 'base' was just established yet I still have to do this:
   require_once '../theDatabase.php';
   require_once '../globals.php';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP parser doesn't parse HTML. It parses *only* things in between `<?php ?>` tags. Basically, your `<base>` tag is meaningless to PHP.

I suggest you don't use `<base>`, as I have *never* seen a reason to use it.

Comment: You already had a +1 so I will give you another and accept your answer. Really damned humbling.  I realize now despite several months of getting used to coding with 2 client-side scripting languages and one server-side language of code in the same file I'm far from having the big-picture and the 'hang of it', but I'm getting there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It takes a while to learn anything and PHP isn't the easiest language to learn, but you'll get the hang of it eventually. Better to learn this stuff now than suffer later ;)

Comment: Thanks, when stuff like this comes up, at least I can re-set my expectation on how far along the path I am.